# What's the most stable IRCD?

Tags: unix, irc

In general I'm looking for an opinion on what's the most stable (and secure) battle tested IRCD out there that's still actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Your IRCD is only as stable as your uplink/server. Most of the mature IRCD daemons will do just fine.